# Media engine error, not hearing sound on local machine

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps

When I try to play a sound with a media element on my local machine I can't hear any sound. But I can hear sound in the simulator(same thing almost right?) and on my surface when I test it on there. It Doesn't work on all my pages too not just one on the local machine only too.

load event goes off in simulator but not in local machine. Also stream isn't null.

```
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Sound/" +selectedCharacterSets[currentCharacterSet].character[currentCharacter].romaji + ".mp3", UriKind.Absolute));
var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
mdeSound.SetSource(stream, file.ContentType);
```

Media failed event going off. `Error: MF_MEDIA_ENGINE_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED : HRESULT 0x8000FFFF`. Does anyone know how to fix this and why its only on local machine?

EDIT: converted mp3 to wma... still doesn't load. converted it to wmv now it plays on local machine... why? I'm still confused. Opening the mp3 in the music app throws an error too, windows media player plays it fine.

Comment: Use MediaInfo to check if there is DRM in your MP3.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with the file you are trying to play. This could be because of DRM or because of bitrates being too high, etc. Windows 8 Pro can play more codecs than Windows 8 RT, but you said it worked on your Surface which is interesting. Try using Audacity or another program to save it as a lower bitrate MP3 or even a basic .WAV file.

It's also interesting that you couldn't play it as WMA but you could as WMV. WMV is video while WMA is audio. You may have a corrupt media stack on your machine.

P.S. The simulator essentially uses Remote Desktop, so there *is* a difference in how the audio gets played.